# list assignment index out of range for 2d array error

Tags: python, list

I looked into answers regarding similar questions but couldn't figure out my problem. I am newbie to python please help.

```
length = 13
breadth = 24
sheet = [ [ 0 for y in range( length ) ] for x in range( breadth ) ]
sheet[length-2][breadth-3] = 1
```

The above code gives me list assignment index out of range error.

Comment: you are working with `list` objects, not arrays.

Comment: Anyway, you've got length and breadth reversed. When you first index into `sheet`, there are `breadth` many elements. When you index into one of the sublists in `sheet`, there are `length` many  elements.

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer, if it helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have either the `list-comprehension` the wrong way around, it should be:

```
length = 13
breadth = 24
sheet = [ [ 0 for x in range( breadth ) ] for y in range( length ) ]
sheet[length-2][breadth-3] = 1
```

Or you have the indexing of the `sheet` `list` the wrong way around, it should be:

```
length = 13
breadth = 24
sheet = [ [ 0 for x in range( length ) ] for y in range( breadth ) ]
sheet[breadth-2][length-3] = 1
```

Both corrections will work fine, but it depends on what you are defining `breadth` and `width` to be.

---

In the first example, the `list` looks like:

```
  #breadth --->
[[0,0 ....  0,0],  #width |
 ...               #      |
 [0,0 ....  0,0],  #      \/
]
```

*there are `width` rows of size `breadth`*

In the second:

```
  #width --->
[[0,0 ....  0,0],  #breadth |
 ...               #        |
 [0,0 ....  0,0],  #        \/
]
```

*there are `breadth` rows of size `width`*

Answer (score 1):

You have the axes mixed up, try using

```
sheet[breadth-3][length-2] = 1
```

Alternatively, you could use `numpy` to do this more elegantly:

```
import numpy as np

breadth = 5
length = 3

sheet = np.zeros(shape=(breadth, length))
sheet[breadth-3, length-2] = 1

sheet.shape
>>> (5, 3)

sheet
>>> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```